Increase WSL screen buffer
I'm working with the Ubunu WSL app from Canonical. When I start the application, this is the runtime directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2022.1.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc.
I would like to increase the screen buffer. Currently it is equal to 9999 but even that is not enough.
9999 is the highest number I can enter, but as that value gets stored, I believe I should be able to find it back in registry and modify it over there. (I performed a search on the mentioned directory and there are not recently modified files, hence my idea that this information should be present in the registry. (... or are all WSL-related settings collected on another place on my computer?))
Does anybody know where the configurations of the WSL Ubuntu app from Canonical are stored?
I seem not to have any WSL configuration relate file, as described in the following Windows search:
DOS_Prompt>dir /S /B "*wsl.conf*"
C:\Users\DDM\AppData\Local\Packages\.
\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows...\.
\LocalState\rootfs\etc\ld.so.conf.d\ld.wsl.conf

Also my WSL doesn't have an idea:
Linux_Prompt:/etc$ find ./ -iname "*wsl*"
./ld.so.conf.d/ld.wsl.conf

Edit:
Hereby a screenshot what I mean: I right-click on the header of the WSL window and choose "Properties". In the popup-menu, I go for the "Layout" tab, this is what I mean:


There is only one WSL configuration file.

@Ramhound: great news, where can I find it?

wsl.conf and .wslconfig one is for the single instance and the other is the global setting

@Ramhound: I've been looking all over my PC, I don't have any WSL related configuration files.

@Ramhound: so the mentioned settings should be stored elsewhere, but where?

You have to create those files as the are only used to change default behavior.

@Ramhound: currently, when I modify the buffer value and restart the WSL, that modified value is taken into account, proving that that value is already saved somewhere. Apparently it's not save in any "wsl.conf" or ".wslconfig" file, as those files don't exist. ... then where is that value saved?

Unclear : If you're calling ubuntu.exe, the maximum is 999 and not 9999. If you're using instead the ubuntu profile in Terminal, you might be referring to the "History size" in Settings, but this doesn't seem to be limited to  9999.

@harrymc: I've added a screenshot of what I mean.
